# Grails latest version for plugin and dependencies?

Tags: grails, version, dependency-management

In my `BuildConfig.groovy`, how do I specify that I want the "latest version" of a particular dependency? Where is this documented? Is this configurable? Meaning, how does this mechanism know that `some-lib-1.0.0rc.jar` (a release candidate) is "less later than" `some-lib-1.0.0.jar` (the production release)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For latest released plugins (plugins published in grails.org) below can be used:

```
plugins {
    compile ':some-plugin:latest.release'
}
```

`latest.release` is something Grails picks up from the list of plugin from `grailsCentral` 
(normally available as `plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml` after running `grails list-plugin` command) under `<user>/.grails/<grailsVersion>` which looks like:

```
<plugins>
...
<plugin name='some-plugin' latest-release='0.1.0'>
    <release version='0.1.0'>
      <title>Some plugin</title>
      <author />
      <authorEmail />
      <description>blah</description>
      <file>url to zip artifact</file>
    </release>
  </plugin>
  ....
</plugins>
```

For latest dependencies/custom plugins, you can try using open ended versions :

```
compile( groupId: 'some-group', name: 'some-lib', version: '[1.0.0,)' )

// It can also be specified as simply as
compile 'some-group:some-lib:[1.0.0)'
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahaptro (+1) - for dependencies you mention that I can "try" your suggestion but that it is "untested". Is this something that is simply not documented in Grails? Also how does this `latest.release` know what versions are the latest? Is this configurable?

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith, but still no answer on whether any of this is documented, or on the configuration of `latest.release`...

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Rightly said. I had no time to test that earlier. But now I did, apparently it is easier then specifying dependency explicitly. Updating answer.

Comment: @smeeb Updated answer for question related to `latest.release`.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1 again), however my plugin is something built in-house, not on Grails Central. Will `latest.release` still work?

Comment: You cannot use that for custom plugins. You can use `':some-plugin:[0.0.1,)'` instead. This will resolve to the latest plugin version available.

Comment: Your "short form" for dependencies/custom plugins is missing a small but very important comma at the end and should be written as `compile 'some-group:some-lib:[1.0.0,)'`. Other than that, excellent answer!